# how to distory session without help of ivalidate method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am facing some problem i want to update login table on session expire  ...
here define method always gives new session and also update data on some condition

```
public HttpSession getNewSession(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

    HttpSession httpSession =  request.getSession(false);

    log.debug("Incoming httpSession.getId() :: " + httpSession.getId());
    long lastAccessedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()-httpSession.getLastAccessedTime())/1000;
    log.debug((System.currentTimeMillis()-httpSession.getLastAccessedTime()) + " milliSecond.");
    log.debug( lastAccessedTime + " Second. ");
    log.debug( lastAccessedTime + " lastAccessedTime>=900");
    if(lastAccessedTime>=900){
        log.debug( "true  lastAccessedTime>=900");
        String userName = null != httpSession.getAttribute(USER_NAME)?httpSession.getAttribute(USER_NAME)+"":"";
        CGLoginService documentManagementService = new CGLoginIMPL();
        if(userName.length()>=1){
            CGLoginDTO cgTrgLoginDTO = new CGLoginDTO();
            cgTrgLoginDTO.setLoginFlag("false");
            cgTrgLoginDTO.setUpdatedDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            cgTrgLoginDTO.setLockFlag("false");
            cgTrgLoginDTO.setLockCount(0);
            CGLoginDTO cgLoginDTO = new CGLoginDTO();
            cgLoginDTO.setLoginId(userName);
            try {
                documentManagementService.updateUsers(cgTrgLoginDTO, cgLoginDTO, null, false);
            } catch (BuisnessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error(" Exception found while updating user is "+e);
            }
        }
        httpSession.invalidate();
        log.debug("httpSession.invalidate();");
    }else{
        log.debug("lastAccessedTime>=900 where session not expire and Outgoing httpSession.getId() :: " + httpSession.getId());
        log.debug("user name :: " +httpSession.getAttribute("userName"));
        if(httpSession !=null && httpSession.getAttribute("userName") !=null){
            log.debug( "true  httpSession !=null && httpSession.getAttribute(USER_NAME) !=null");
            Object userName = httpSession.getAttribute("userName") ;
            Object userRole = httpSession.getAttribute("userRole");
            Object userToken = (httpSession.getAttribute("userToken") !=null)?httpSession.getAttribute("userToken"):"";
            Object lastLogin = (httpSession.getAttribute("lastLogin") !=null)?httpSession.getAttribute("lastLogin"):"";

            httpSession.invalidate();

            httpSession = request.getSession(true);

            httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(900);
            httpSession.setAttribute("userName", userName);
            httpSession.setAttribute("userRole", userRole);
            httpSession.setAttribute("userToken", userToken);
            httpSession.setAttribute("lastLogin",lastLogin);
            log.debug("Outgoing httpSession.getId() :: " + httpSession.getId());
            return httpSession;
        }else
            log.debug("session not map define value ");
            httpSession = null;
    }
    return httpSession;
}
```

i also use HttpSessionListener interface for this stuff but session.invalidate() method also use this destroy method of listener  ..
because all time need new session id....

Answer (score 0):

you can remove values from session

```
 httpSession.removeAttribute("userName");
```